# Assistance with conditioning formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Hello friends,
I am creating a Journal ledger using Crystal Report 
I have a parameter for opening balance and a formula for balance in which I have the following condition:

```
global numberVar  ba;
if (ba=0) then
ba:={@opningbalance};
ba:=ba+{ledger.dabit} - {ledger.credit};
```

opening 100

```
 debit   credit    balance 
  100        0      200
    0       100     100
    0       100       0     
  100        0      200
```

it is working fine but if the balance filed answer = 0, my balance figure is out because my condition is true.
Please assist me.

[Here is the link for the image of the table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGPGC.png)

Comment: opening 100

 dabit credit balance 
  100 0 200
   0 100 100
   0    100 0  
  100 0 200

Comment: didn't get you can you eloborate more? what do you need if a `ba=0`

Comment: if ba=0 so formual get again opning balance and forget dabit credit figure

Comment: opening 100


 dabit credit balance 
  100 0 200
   0 100 100
   0    100 0  
  100 0 200

Comment: siva are you there sorry i am new user in stack over flow

Comment: how can i show you  snap short  my problem

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PGPGC.png                check this link

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I think below is what you are trying to do.

```
global numberVar  ba;
if ba=0 then {@opningbalance}
else
ba+{ledger.dabit}-{ledger.credit}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry to say that I still didn't complete idea of your problem but to the extent I understand below is the solution
```

first question here is if `ba=0` then also you want to do the calculation of `debit` and `credit` then remove the if condtion and just place

```
ba:=ba+{ledger.dabit}-{ledger.credit};
```

If you don't want to remove the if condition then use this

```
global numberVar  ba;
if(ba=0)
then
ba:=ba+{ledger.dabit}-{ledger.credit};
ba:=ba+{ledger.dabit}-{ledger.credit};
```

but first one is suggested approach